# Quarkus batch - Is command mode applicable in running batch in quarkus?

Tags: java, spring-boot, quarkus

I currently have a batch in quarkus which is being run on cron jobs and is being triggered through an http request call. I use the curl command in hitting the endpoint that needs to be triggered on a specific time.

I need to change it to something like ApplicationRunner from Spring Boot, which only stays alive when needed unlike an endpoint which is always on.

I've found something about command mode on quarkus but i am not sure if this would solve my problem.

Hoping I can get some suggestions as i am just new in quarkus.

Thank you!

Comment: There is a quarkus extension for JBeret Which is similar to spring-batch, but I'm not sure if it has released yet. Are you running quarkus inside a kubernetes environment or just bare metal with jvm?

Comment: Running inside kubernetes

Comment: You can use Kubernetes cron jobs to start a pod with quarkus to execute the cron operations if you don't want to have the pod running continiously

Comment: Rather than a quarkus questión this is more an Architecture question regarding the architecture of your solution and what the component you are trying to implement must do, and who is going to invoke it to do his things

Comment: Sounds like you just want GraalVM to create an executable, not Quarkus. Otherwise, Knative can be used to serve a function on an endpoint